# Why is it so hard to rank up?

Tags: league-of-legends

I am unfortunately in Bronze III. Which is basically hell on Earth. When I check the leaderboards all of the people in bronze have less than 50 wins. I have over 100. I have around a 50% win ratio.

How is this even remotely possible? Is Riot's ranking system really just that pathetic? Or am I just the worst League of Legends player in human history?

I am looking for advice for getting out of bronze but I'm also wondering why it is that most people in bronze have way less experience playing in bronze (i.e. less wins which would indicate less games played)

One thing I have thought about is that for some reason I bought an experience boost. This would put me against players who for the most part have more experience than me. I also started playing ranked earlier than is normal which may contribute to my win ratio being a little less than 50%.

With my most used champions I have win percentages that are all above 50%.

Comment: There is no getting out of bronze solo, I suggest you find a duo partner :P

Comment: @Brian I played with a duo partner and we're both in bronze. Usually it's not us but our teammates being extremely bad. I think this is also the case with Kecoey.

Comment: @Brian I was able to get to gold solo, but quit when my placement quickly went to low silver.

Comment: @Richard A Yes my losses are 90% of the time completely determined by my teammates

Comment: The best advice I have is to play the game and have fun with it. Don't be worried about where you're at currently--just try to improve and see what you could've done better.

Comment: Getting an experience boost makes no sense since you are already 30  if you can play ranked.

Comment: I got the experience boost when I was like level 20

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ4vPCY11eM&feature=endscreen&NR=1 i know this isn't really helpful, but this might give you an idea of what most of us think of when someone complains about being ranked low

Comment: @Ravekner I'm not complaining I am looking for answers. I am now in bronze I and expect to be in silver soon. I am never toxic. EVER. That is the easiest way to lose games. And I still disagree that it is possible to be winning 70-80% of games in bronze. I can see 60% or even 65 but higher than that is hard to believe.

Comment: @Kecoey I find it impossible to believe that your losses are your teammates' faults 90% of the time. The best players in the world know that when they lose, there's always something that they *personally* could have done better to give their team a better chance. You have the wrong outlook.

Comment: @kecoey There are smurfs with 150 win/ 1 loss records out there. A good player can carry his entire team pretty much every single game. You are WRONG about bronze being impossible to win reliably. Here's an example of a smurf account from a top leona player who started at bronze and moved up to gold 5 with a 120 to 1 win ratio as leona (ignore the other characters he uses for trolling of course). http://www.lolking.net/summoner/na/43650365#ranked-stats

Comment: @Lawton Try to think before you post irrelevant comments. Obviously he is way better than me. This means that in his first 10 placement games he did EXTREMELY well and DID NOT END UP IN BRONZE. Don't act like you have any idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have a 50% win ratio, then you are in the ranking where you belong, since you are winning as much as you are losing, therefore you are at your true ranking already.

If you want to raise in ranks, you'll need to raise in win ratio, so you just need to start winning more games (ie. play better, learn more about the game, etc.)

Rankings are not about the amount of wins, but your ratio of wins to losses. If it were just about win amount by itself, then the person who plays the most would be top ranking, even if they weren't the best player.

Comment: Because of this you will be placed against the same skill level players. If your win ratio goes down you will be placed lower but if you start winning more then 50% you will be placed against players with higher skills.

Comment: I understand this. However, as a solo player my wins are extremely dependent on the other players in the game. So a 50% win ratio is about as good as gets.

Comment: Bronze is notorious for being the battle zone for the uninitiated. Those that lack the knowledge, experience and understanding of the game(as well as champions and team strategies) will remain there until they take the time to improve themselves. I'm not saying you are a bad player, but I am saying you obviously have areas that you could work on improving.

Comment: Again I find it very hard to believe that it is possible to have a win percentage that is much higher than 50%. If you play well consistently, which I believe that I do, then whether or not you win is determined by whether you got put on the better team.

Comment: Then your problem is not execution but team play or coordination. Talk to your teammates and make tactical decisions. You have to acquire this skill until you can progress in the leagues.

Comment: Obviously you do not remember bronze. People do not listen. And you can't tell them not to do stupid stuff constantly

Comment: There is a difference between telling people not to do stupid things and actually giving constructive advice like "place a ward here instead of here as it gives us more vision and a larger warning area", communication doesnt always mean typing something out either, with the newest ping system, there are lots of things you can point out to teammates without typing a word. If and I mean "IF" in a big way, you think you are skilled enough, you may want to try learning a champion that can splitpush/backdoor very well mid/late game. This can in all likelyhood allow you to carry out of bronze.

Comment: This is not true. If you for example lose 100 games then you will be at the bottom of the ladder. Then you win 20 games in a row (for example) and you get to the next level because of the points you get. That means that you leveled with a 1/5 win ratio.

Comment: @AdamArold You leveled with a burst of 20/0 win ratio. It doesn't consider *that long* averages that much. It has a much bigger emphasis on the short term success.

Comment: But if you level up by winning 10 games in a row then you win/lose in a 1:2 ratio about 100 games then rinse and repeat you will end up with a negative win-lose ratio but still leveling up.

Answer (score 3):

There's a few things to keep in mind regarding this.

**Fact 1:**
League of Legends is, at its core, a team game. Regardless of how good you are, you won't win a 1v5, and if your teammates play badly enough, there may be nothing you can do to save the game. There are, in fact, some games that your teammates lose for you.

**Fact 2:**
Despite this, individual skill still plays a part. If you consistently play better than your counterpart on the other team, you'll have more power in teamfights, and be able to assist your team better overall. Although being a good player won't get you a 90% win ratio, if you're better than the people around you, you should be able to get something along the lines of a 60% win rate. In short, many people who feel they don't belong in bronze are often at least partially to blame for some of their losses.

**Common problem 1:**
There's many important skills that most bronze level players lack. The first one is *map awareness*. One of the easiest ways to die is by wandering around in the map when you have no idea where the enemy team is. Then all of a sudden three champions jump out of a bush, and kill you with little trouble. Many players will attribute it to bad luck (or worse, blame their allies/their champion).

**The solution:**
Fortunately, it's pretty simple to avoid this, with the invention known as the *sight ward*. Wards are a mere 75 gold (or 125 gold if you want the upgraded version), and give you vision of an area for three minutes. By placing these strategically at choke points, you'll know where the enemy team is. This lets you avoid their attempts to gank you, and lets your team set up ambushes for them. Keep in mind, a champion kill is (on average) 300 gold, with another 150 assist gold. That means if it takes four wards to avoid dying once, you still broke even. In practice, they'll save your life far more than that.

**Common problem 2:**
A lot of players simply don't know how to teamfight. There's five enemies pushing mid, and your team decides to engage despite two of your players being somewhere else. Thirty seconds later, all three of you are dead, and only one enemy died. Then the other two come back to try to stop the push, and they die as well. The enemy gets the ace, a couple towers, and perhaps the game.

**The solution:**
In the above scenario, you did not lose a teamfight. You lost a 3v5 and a 2v4, both of which are heavily in the enemy team's favor. Quite simply, the team with more chamipons has the advantage. Unless you're very ahead and can take a couple enemies out of the fight quickly, don't engage when you're at a disadvantage. If they jump on half your team and murder them without taking damage, don't throw your life away trying for revenge, just run! Above all, *act as a team.* If they blow all their abilities killing your tank, jumping into the 4v5 can potentially work. Having all four members of your team stay back under the turret is another option. However, if two members of your team go in and the other two retreat, you're just giving them free kills. Work together, or die alone.

**Other notes:**
Once you get a better feel for teamfighting and how to control the map, don't be afraid to try to take charge and suggest things to your team. However, make sure you remain polite when doing this. I don't care if you're 13-3 and your ADC is 1-6, if you're yelling at him for his poor play, he much less likely to listen to you. Try to control your frustration and offer constructive criticism, and perhaps go down and help out his lane. In short, if you can keep hurt feelings to a minimum, you have a much better chance of working as a team in fights.

**TLDR:**
Remember, individual skill in the laning phase is only one part of being a good player. If you have no map awareness and no teamfighting ability, you're going to die a lot in mid-late game, and probably remain stuck in bronze. If you can improve these aspects of your game (and encourage your teammates to do them as well), you'll find yourself dying less, getting more kills, and overall winning more games.

Hopefully this helped, and good luck on the fields of justice.

Answer (score 1):

While you're in the bronze just enjoy it and try to learn more about team coordination, communicating, creating strategies including your self surviving strategy, item builds, placing wards, and team roles.

If your team doesn't listen to you, just leave them some advice and just cope up with them. If your team don't want to place wards, then you you're self need to place it.

Just remember that when your solo queuing, each of you are stranger. So sometimes coordinating is hard. Always help them even though they don't help you.

Comment: Tottaly agree that. Always be nice to people don't blame them we all do mistakes even more in bronze.I Have never been to ELO Hell but a friend of mine get out of if just by playing support. Why support cause,even the stupidiest people, when they have vision they, dont get caught !!! if you show them the guy in the jungle they will not die and if an ennemy is isolated in your jungle and you have vision on him HE will get caught ;-). You don't have to be that guy that after spending 25 mn afk brain farming top is flaming his team because he gets 200CS and 3 kills and evryone is a feeder :-D

Answer (score 0):

After 20 games in ranked you should have a good idea on how good you are with that champion, play the ones you have above 60% and more win ratio more even if it means sacrificing a bit of fun.

Here is a good website for the complete mindset you need in ranked
www.realelohell.wordpress.com

The articles are detailed on the mindset you need to win, apply every little thing you
can.
Final advice, if you win lane very hard, ward and work on getting 2 turrets, then help your team.