# What champions are able to splitpush/backdoor well mid-to-late game?

Tags: league-of-legends

I recently read this advice:

> you may want to try learning a champion that can splitpush/backdoor very well mid/late game. This can in all likelihood allow you to carry out of bronze.

but I don't know which champions this is talking about. Which champions are able to do this?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you read that tidbit?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120319/why-is-it-so-hard-to-rank-up/120326#comment162626_120326

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's three things you want in a split push champion.

The first is the ability to take down towers quickly. You only have so much time before the enemy team figures out you're there, and you need to make the most of it. Similarly, you want to be able to clear out minion waves quickly, though this is a smaller issue as a lot more champions can do this easily.

The second is dueling capability. Often times the enemy team might send only one or two champions to stop your push while the rest try to continue what they're doing. Certain champions excel at winning 1v1's and even some 1v2's, and if you're playing one of those, you can just kill them and continue pushing.

The third quality is escape ability. Sooner or later the entire enemy team is going to come after you, and at that point it'd be a great idea to try and get out alive.

A very good (and very cheap) split pusher is Master Yi. His abilities include a massive AD boost, a massive AS boost, an incredible movement boost, and even resistance to slows. This is literally everything a split pusher could ever ask for, as you'll be able to murder towers and lone enemy champions, and he's nearly impossible to catch.

However, there's three other things you should do to increase the chances of succeeding with your split push.

The first is to choose your spots well. If the enemy team is currently teamfighting your allies in the bottom lane, by all means, go take out a couple top lane towers. If three of them are dead and you have vision on the other two, again, push to your hearts desire. If they're all live and none of them are visible? That's a bad time to push.

The second is to ward well. There's this nifty 75 gold item known as a sight ward, that lets you see a small area of the map. Plant these things at choke points around the area you plan on pushing, and you'll know when the enemy team is coming for you. This makes escaping much easier, and is likely to save your life several times through a match. (They're also very important for normal laning and teamfighting, but that's another issue.)

The third and final thing is the teleport summoner spell. If you've got a huge minion wave pushing top but you're currently back at base, teleport there and you'll get the tower down before they know what hit them. On the contrary, if you've just taken down an inhibitor and you know they're coming for you (thanks to those wards you placed earlier), you can use it like a much faster recall to get out of there... possibly to another lane you can push down.

On the flip side, keep in mind that teleport is also an amazing way to stop a split push as well. If you see three enemy champions with teleport, you might be better off just trying to teamfight. Similarly, if they have abilities that can effectively emulate a teleport (Twisted Fate, Nocturne, or Pantheon's ultimates), you need to be a lot more careful, as they can appear at any time and try to kill you.

One last thing, although split pushing is a valid and extremely effective tactic, keep in mind that there are times where it's just better to teamfight. If the enemy team's main push would kill your nexus before your backdoor can destroy theirs, you need to go back and help out your team. This can also apply to fights around Baron, as winning that buff is often enough to seal the game. Then again, in the EU vs NA all star game, a split push during a baron fight took out everything in NA's base short of the Nexus itself, so use your own judgement.

Good luck, and happy split pushing!

Comment: Great answer, but I'd like to note that it's probably not necessary to be strong in both dueling *and* escaping.

Comment: It's not strictly necessary, but it's definitely helpful. If they send one champion to deal with you, it's great to be a powerful dueler, but if the entire team comes after you, you're better off trying to escape. You can still split push without one of those qualities, but it'll be harder.

Comment: That's a really thorough explanation. Some more suggestions apart from Yi?

Comment: For example Olaf would be a really good champion according to your criteria.

Comment: dont forget shaco - his ult significantly increases his damage against turrets and also acts as a tank against the turret, his boxes are free wards, and his Q is a flash+invis - perfect splitpusher. add a tp and he can split push then tp into teamfiht

Comment: Tryndamere is another amazing split pusher, considering his ultimate. Garen and Riven aren't quite as strong in that role, but still pretty good. I'm not entirely sure how Olaf works as a split pusher, I don't really use him much.

Comment: Teemo can work well too, he has a fast get-away (uncatchable) and can plant shrooms in choke points to not only scout but to slow the team from approaching, if you're feeling tricky you can also stand still for an invis after you run a little bit so you can continue to push again once they give up on the chase. The only thing he lacks is high tower damage, but you can compensate for this with damaging items (even AP hits towers hard).

Comment: Nidalee can split push very good too. 
Even if you build her ap, heal yourself before atacking a tower and when you see enemies coming, R + W run FTW

Answer (score 1):

I let you a list of champs that can split push very well:

- Shen
- Twisted Fate
- Nocturne
- Pantheon
- Nidalee
- Nasus (With TP)
- Master Yi
- Shaco
- Udyr
- Evelynn
- Teemo
- Mundo
- Shyvana
- Sivir
- Olaf
- Khazix
- Tryndamere
- Xin Zhao
- Singed
- Aatrox
- Lucian
- Zed
- Yasuo

According to Nicholas1024's answer those are the best champs to split push.
But per example karthus can split push well, because he dont need to stay in tf to do damage (Whatever I think it's hard to split push with karthus)

EDIT:
Gangplank can do the same of karthus with his ult, but is the same for him, if your team is in troubles in the TF, your ulti can't save them.

Comment: Where is Olaf? He has ad steroid. With his ult + ghost he can escape from **anywhere**, his dueling potential due to his passive is exceptional, and he can clear waves with his Q extremely fast.

Answer (score 0):

You need two abilities.

> An ability to push quickly.
>   .
>
> An ability to escape. A hardescape like a tp (like TF, Panth, Shen) or an ability to escape with very few life (tryndamere).

A few champs fit this role perfectly, there are TF, Shen with Sunfire, Pantheon with sunfire, Singed, and such.

The main problem when split pushing is that opponents can come and kill you 3v1 if you don't escape safely.